# Not getting proper capslock on validation using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an issue using `ngCapsLock` module in Angular.js.I need capslock on message only on password filed but here when i am pressing capslock in any other field of my form rather than password field the message is also displaying.Please check my code.

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email Id :</span>
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.email.$touched && billdata.email.$invalid }">
<input type="email" name="email" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="User email" ng-model="user_email" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.email.$error" ng-if="billdata.email.$touched">
p ng-message="email" style="color:#F00;">This needs to be a valid email</p>
<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs valid email format(e.g-abc@gmail.com).</p>
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': billdata.pass.$touched && billdata.pass.$invalid }">
    <input type="password " name="pass" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).*_.*/" >
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.pass.$error" ng-if="billdata.pass.$touched">
    <p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your password should be 8.</p>
    <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the special character like at least one number,upper case,lower case letter and underscore.</p>
    <p class="caps-lock-alert" ng-show='isCapsLockOn' style="color:#F00;">Capslock is on</p>
    </div>
```

Here my requirement is when user will do caps lock on only in the password field the message will come.But here many other field like email,user name,etc..are there my problem is when user is doing caps lock on in any other field rather than password field the message is also coming which should not display.I have included the `ngCapsLock`.Please help me.

Comment: can you post the email field?

Comment: Email and password both have  id="contactno" remove this field from any one and check

Comment: @GandharvGarg : i have changed but still issue is there.